UnifiedEmail Full Details
We are attempting to build a bespoke solution to render activity captured by Einstein Activity Capture. The purpose will be to filter which emails are displayed based on criteria within the message.
We have been able to retrieve details of the email by utilising the following query but cannot get any more information about the body of the email, only a subset of the data from the "Snippet" field which is restricted to 255 characters.
SELECT ActivityDateTime, ActivitySubType, ActivityType, DetailId, Direction, InternalEventKey, IsInsightAvailable, IsPrivate, Snippet, Subject FROM UnifiedEmail WHERE Id IN (SELECT ActivityId FROM UnifiedActivityRelation WHERE RelatedId = 'CONTACT ID')

Does anyone know where the full details within the email can be retrieved from? I understand with EAC that activity is stored in AWS and streamed to Salesforce and therefore not in the usual emailMessage object.
